# How to real time data after every second?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show real time data, currently i used this code

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
            $('#load_updates').load('comment.php').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="load_updates"></div>
</body>
```

Now everything is fine, this code is working and shows data from comment.php, but the problem is that it refreshes data after 10 seconds and it's too much time. I tried to reduce the milliseconds but it's not working

Comment: Can you show the code you tried using when reducing the milliseconds?

Comment: here is edited code
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_updates').load('comment.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 2000); 

</script>

Comment: You need to consider the time of your request too. Your page "comment.php" need to be faster than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are some technologies to build a real time application. You can use WebSockets for example.

This link has some options:
https://entwickler.de/webandphp/building-realtime-web-apps-with-php-125787.html